# How can I make password optional when using authlogic and LDAP authentication?

Tags: ldap, authlogic

I am creating an application for which I am trying to use LDAP with authlogic for login authentication. I want to accept just the username and log the user in if he is on the LDAP server. For this, I need to disable the password validation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.validate_password_field = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your User model where you call acts_as_authentic, this *might* do the trick:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.require_password_confirmation = false
  config.ignore_blank_passwords = true
end
```

These config options, among others, can be found in lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb (in version 2.1.3).

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work. I looked in the source code for authlogic and it looks like UserSession model still needs password when it tries to save it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the authlogic_ldap addon that I modified for my app. I make the mistake of including `login_field :ldap_login` in the User class. 
I also had a `stack level too deep` error initially, but I reverted authlogic from v3.0.3 to v3.0.2 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful doing this with Open ID (same idea, password not stored by my app) by not having a password column in the `users` table and using this config for Authlogic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.crypted_password_field = false
  end
end
```

Without setting `crypted_password_field`, there were errors generated during user saves.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for me. 

Prior to this I used authlogic-openid gem to create a login which doesn't require password.

I refered to this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic

Comment: It still says "Password can not be blank" even though I didn't provide a password field on the UI.

Comment: You need to make sure there is no password field in the `users` table (or whatever table underlies your `acts_as_authentic` model).  This is what generates a password attribute on the model.

Comment: My user model doesn't have password field but still it gives me the same error message. I feel like password is required in authlogic gem.